# asp.net core 2, identity w/windows authentication but database managed roles

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, windows-authentication

I have a custom `IClaimsTransformation` thanks to @jim-karnopp.  All appears to work fine aside from when I try to add a user to the database that doesn't already exist.

```
var user = identity.Name

AppUser newuser = new AppUser()
            {
                UserName =  user,
                EmailConfirmed = false,
                PhoneNumberConfirmed = false,
                TwoFactorEnabled = false,
                LockoutEnabled = false,
                AccessFailedCount = 0
            };

            var createUser = await _userManager.CreateAsync(newuser);
```

Is there a better way to add a windows authenticated user to the identity database?    I'm receiving a 'InvalidUserName' "can only contain letters and digits" error currently.  Because `identity.name` equals `DOMAIN\\username`

Is there a way to store the windows authenticated username in the identity db?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Configure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-configuration?tabs=aspnetcore2x&view=aspnetcore-2.1) the username validator to allow .

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(options => {
    options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters = "allowed characters here";
});
```

Comment: Thank you @blowdart!  `options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters = null;` removes the validation entirely for those referencing this post in their searches